# How to use Bash read with a timeout?

Tags: bash, io, timeout

I can ask the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> by using `read`, and have him wait by calling `sleep`. But I can’t think of a way of doing both at the same time. I would like the user to be given the choice:

*Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to Cancel, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue or just wait 10 seconds*

How can I do that?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

In `bash`<sup>(1)</sup>, the `read` command has a `-t` option where you can specify a timeout. From the man page:

> `read [-ers] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-a aname] [-p prompt] [-n nchars] [-d delim] [name ...]`
>
> `-t timeout:`  cause `read` to time out and return failure if a complete line of input is not read within timeout seconds. This option has no effect if `read` is not reading input from the terminal or a pipe.

Transcript below (without hitting ENTER):

```bash
$ date ; read -t 10 -p "Hit ENTER or wait ten seconds" ; echo ; date
Tue Feb 28 22:29:15 WAST 2012
Hit ENTER or wait ten seconds
Tue Feb 28 22:29:25 WAST 2012
```

Another, hitting ENTER after a couple of seconds:

```bash
$ date ; read -t 10 -p "Hit ENTER or wait ten seconds" ; date
Tue Feb 28 22:30:17 WAST 2012
Hit ENTER or wait ten seconds
Tue Feb 28 22:30:19 WAST 2012
```

And a final one, hitting CTRL-C:

```bash
$ date ; read -t 10 -p "Hit ENTER or wait ten seconds" ; echo ; date
Tue Feb 28 22:30:29 WAST 2012
Hit ENTER or wait ten seconds
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> If you're doing this in a script, make *sure* that it's running under `bash` rather than some other shell.

You can do that in many ways such as by using a `#!` shebang line of some type, specifying the shell when you run the command, or making sure your system will run `bash` by default for scripts.

Comment: I absolutely love it when detailed answers like this are given. Kudos to you!

Comment: ubuntu. -t - illegal option

Comment: @ses, make sure you're using the bash builtin, not some external tool.

Comment: If you're writing a shell script, make sure that it starts with a `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`. The latter may or may not work depending which binary `/bin/sh` actually is. You're allowed to write `#!/bin/sh` if and *only if* your script is POSIX compatible, which it pretty much sure is not.

Comment: When using this, make sure your script is `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`, because the `-t` option is not POSIX compatible (i.a.w. the script may not work on every machine)

Comment: @Marian, since the question is actually *tagged* `bash`, it's probably not necessary to mention that :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, not for the person who asked, but for others who might stumble upon this. ( Plus, many people seem to use bashisms with a `sh` shebang, so it's good to mention it every now and then :) )

Comment: Right on!  Thank you.  I found this answer in Google - Nov 2017

Comment: For the shebang, it may be useful to first use the `which bash` command to find the exact string to us eon your system.

Comment: The bash man page also mentions the **TMOUT** shell variable.

Comment: To add to the POSIX comment by @MikkoRantalainen - you can use a nice little tool called ShellCheck to test your scripts for syntax errors and POSIX compatibility. https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Peter, even though my answer always stated `bash` and never had `/bin/sh` anywhere in it, I'm succumbing to the pressure after a decade or so to explicitly state the requirement :-)

Comment: I think it's actually safer to bet that `bash` is in `/bin/bash` than the `env` being in `/usr/bin/env`. In case of e.g. `python`, it's the other way around. As such, your shebang should be `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: @Mikko, see https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/finding-bash-perl-python-portably-using-env.html or (better) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my. I don't think I've ever seen a system where `env` is not located there but I have seen places where people wanted a custom `bash`. For example, I made some modifications to `bash` many moons ago and wanted to be able to log in as a specific user to run my changed one (for the test scripts, not the login one).

Comment: @paxdiablo Okay, I agreet that if you want to support changing `PATH` to allow using customized `bash` version then having `/usr/bin/env` would make sense. My point was that if you don't trust that `bash` is installed in `/bin/bash` you cannot trust that `env` is installed in `/usr/bin/env` either. As for the answer, the important part is `bash` vs `sh`, not using path to `bash` vs `env bash`. For scripting, I'll continue to use `#!/bin/bash` because I write my scripts to work with any version of `bash` and dropping the `env` saves you one `execve()` in the background.

Comment: For details about using `env` or not, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/20336

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen, added the other option to the answer.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen the trust levels are not the same - we have only convention to trust that `bash` is in `/bin` because there is no standard about even having `bash` as part of the base system - but we have every reason to trust that any system in use today has `env` (because it's in POSIX) as part of the base system. So already we have reason to expect `env` to exist *in a standard system directory* even if `bash` doesn't exist or only exists somewhere under `/opt` or `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: According to POSIX, you indeed have `env` but you cannot know it's path. And you cannot use shebang (`!#"`) line without an absolute path so you must know the full path. According to POSIX, you should have installation method that modifies the shebang line to match the local system (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53116875/334451) but if you don't want to have that, go with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` if you want `PATH` environment variable to affect the selection, or `#!/bin/bash` if you want the system installed `bash` with optimal performance (using `env` causes extra `stat()` + `exec()` syscalls).

Comment: All this discussion of shebang lines is interesting but actually have nothing to do with the question or answer. I put it in the answer simply as an example of ensuring you're running the script under `bash` rather than some other shell. I'm going to make that clearer.

Answer (score 18):

The `read` builtin has a timeout.

```
read -t 10
```

will do it

Comment: Yes but how to show the countdown?

Comment: for me this is causing the program to exit.  I do have the #!/bin/bash shebang, and after the timeout it just exits and doesnt continue.  i cant figure out why.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the thoughtful answers above, the return value from the read is useful to distinguish between an empty  response from the user (for example "Press Enter" for the default action) and a timeout.

```
read -t 5 -p "Prompt " RESP
if [[ $? -gt 128 ]] ; then
    echo -e "\nTimeout"
else
    echo "Response = \"$RESP\""  # adding quotes so empty strings are obvious
fi
```

Another useful tidbit is that the `-p "prompt "` is written to stderr (not stdout) so if you're redirecting stderr, the prompt will not be displayed. An example of this would be logging an execution trace to a log file for later analysis. To use `read -p Prompt` in this case you can redirect stderr to the user for just the read statement.

```
set -x
exec 2>logfile
read -t 5 -p "Prompt " RESP 2>/dev/tty
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) :

> `read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt]`*`[-t timeout]`*`[-u fd] [name ...]`