# press enter on the installation shell script

Tags: php, shell

In the installation of my system, it compiles a module called php ssh2, which asks to select a patch (as shown on the picture in red).

It does not need a patch, so you don't have to do anything other than just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I just need it to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue the build - Is there some way for me to do this in shell script / to remove this confirmation, to make press <kbd>Enter</kbd> automatically?

[image]

Comment: set the command line options?

Comment: Please tell us more about your installation system. What operating system, and what installation system?

Comment: Maybe you could use a timer..lets say for 5 sec and if no key pressed move to next instruction. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483633/press-enter-or-wait-10seconds-to-continue.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your php ssh2 script is called `myprogram`, then you can do this

```
echo -ne '\n' | ./myprogram
```

`\n` will simulate the enter

Answer (score 1):

As a non elegant but working solution I have found that in some cases the only way to script the ENTER was redirecting a file with that only char on it. Similar to previous solution:

```
cat enter.txt | ./myprogram
```

To create de file just do:

```
vi enter.txt
<press i>
<press ENTER>
<press ESCAPE>
:wq
```