# How can I allow a shell script to be paused during execution?

Tags: shell

Let's say I have a script which acts as an alarm. Say you set it for five minutes and it does the following:

```
printf '%s\n' 'Alarm set for 5 minutes'
sleep 300 && printf '%s\n' 'Alarm!'
```

How can I implement a way to continuously monitor for a pause key, say "p" or "SPC", then wait until a key is pressed again to resume normal execution of the script? I want a way for the user to pause the alarm.

Edit: To clarify, I want to continuously monitor for a pause key *while* running other code. This is as opposed to stopping execution to listen on stin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Press enter or wait 10 seconds to continue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483633/press-enter-or-wait-10-seconds-to-continue)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that particular question, since there is not invocation or `read` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily if you accept sending a signal as the method to abort the timer:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '%s\n' 'Alarm set for 5 minutes.  ^C to continue'
sleep 300 &
trap : INT
if wait; then
    echo Timer complete
else
    echo Timer aborted
fi
```

Note that this implementation does not actually stop the `sleep` process, and if that process is doing something more significant, you will probably want to terminate it.  (Instead of doing nothing in the trap, send a signal to the child.)

Answer (score 0):

Many shells have a builtin `read` function that allows you to read from stdin. You can use this to make your program interactive.

However, if you need to do this kind of I/O etc., I think you should shift away from shell to a real programming language.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below

```
// alarm running = true
while true
do
   //running  running is true resume or start alarm
   /** pseudo code
       if running == true
           start or resume alarm
       else 
           pause alarm
       your alarm start or re
    **/
  IFS= read -r -t 0.5 -n 1 -s holder && var="$holder"
  if [ "$var" == "p" ]
    then
          #running = false
         echo "You have pause your alarm "
  elif [ "$var" == "R" ]
   then
      #running = true
     echo "start your timer"
   fi
done
```