# What is the recommended POSIX sh shebang

Tags: shell, sh, posix

I have read that if you want to use Bash in a portable way you should use the shebang:

`#!/usr/bin/env bash`

But now I am wondering: When I want to state explicitly that I do not rely on Bash, but instead, wrote a POSIX compliant script, should I use:

`#!/bin/sh`

Or is `#!/usr/bin/env sh` preferable here too?

Comment: Isn't `#!/usr/bin/env sh` counterproductive? If `/usr` is on separate partition, scripts with `#!/bin/sh` can be used even if `/usr` is not mounted, whereas `#!/usr/bin/env sh` would fail, even though `sh` is in `/bin`. I agree that's somewhat rare situation, but still.

Comment: Indeed, for the default shell (like sh) that might be a problem, but for other shells (e.g., bash) it seems to be [necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/what-is-the-preferred-bash-shebang#comment59287349_10376606).

Comment: Even with `bash`, it stretches the definition of portable. All it says is "use whatever program named `bash` is first in your path". It doesn't say anything about what that version of `bash` should be (3.2? 4.0? 4.1? 4.2? 4.3? 4.4? 5.0?), or even that the program named `bash` even *is* Bash. Document what needs to run your script; let the user worry about how to specify that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Formal perspective

The *informative section* of the [POSIX specification for
sh: Application Usage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_16) states
that you cannot rely on the `sh` executable being installed at `/bin/sh`.

> Applications should note that the standard *PATH* to the shell cannot be
>   assumed to be either **/bin/sh** or **/usr/bin/sh,** and should be
>   determined by interrogation of the *PATH* returned by
>   [getconf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html)
>   *PATH*, ensuring that the returned pathname is an absolute pathname and not
>   a shell built-in.
>
> For example, to determine the location of the standard sh utility:
>
> ```
> command -v sh
> ```

However, instead of suggesting the use of `env` to use the appropriate PATH,
it suggests that shell scripts should be modified at installation time to use
the full path to `sh`:

> Furthermore, on systems that support executable scripts (the "`#!`"
>   construct), it is recommended that applications using executable scripts
>   install them using
>   [getconf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html)
>   *PATH* to determine the shell pathname and update the "`#!`" script
>   appropriately as it is being installed (for example, with
>   [sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)).

#### In practice

I mostly write POSIX shell scripts and, in practice, every GNU/Linux system
(Red Hat and Debian-based) – and others such as Cygwin and OS X – has a
POSIX-compliant `sh` either installed to `/bin/sh` or available as a soft or
hard link at this path. I’ve never needed to use `env` to cater for systems
where `sh` does not use this path.

There may be some Unix systems where a POSIX-compliant `sh` is not available
as `/bin/sh`. The POSIX specification suggests that it might be installed on
some systems as `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`. As I understand it, this is (was?) true
for Solaris systems where `/bin/sh` is an earlier version of the Bourne shell
which predates POSIX. In this case, using `env sh` would not be guaranteed to help as it could still find the Bourne shell (at `/bin/sh`) before the POSIX shell at `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`.

#### Summary

If you’re writing POSIX shell scripts for common Unix and Linux operating
systems, simply use `#!/bin/sh` as the shebang.

In rare cases where `/bin/sh` is a Bourne shell instead of a POSIX-compliant
shell, you would have to modify the shebang to use the appropriate full path
to the POSIX shell.

In either case, there’s no benefit to using `#!/usr/bin/env sh` – and would be
more likely to fail than simply using `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: Okay, so your recommendation is to use installation tools (e.g., configure, make) when possible and stick with `#!/bin/sh` otherwise?

Comment: @JepZ I've updated my answer. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Wouldn't people who *want* the POSIX semantics on Solaris simply make sure `/usr/xpg4/bin` comes before `/usr` in their `PATH` anyway?

Comment: @tripleee Good point. I've never personally used Solaris (only GNU/Linux, Cygwin and OS X) -- but if I had to, that's what I'd do.

Comment: @JepZ That's what I would recommend. From the developer, the shebang is a *recommendation*; the *installer* knows where the correct interpreter lives on the local system.

Comment: Python installation tools will replace any shebang containing `python` (conventionally `#!python` as the minimal example) with whatever installer-specified path is correct and appropriate. (This handles both "non-standard" paths and the difference between Python 2 and Python 3, which may both be installed locally.)

Comment: It's better to use `#!/usr/bin/env sh`, to make sure that your shell is the same as the one you may invoke as `sh` from within your script. See my answer for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I would say `#!/usr/bin/env sh` is preferable.

Some portable constructs, e.g. [the loop over the results of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice), require `sh` to be called explicitly. Consider this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ... some commands here ...
find . -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    # ... commands processing "$file" ...
  done' find-sh {} +
```

The commands at the beginning will be run by `/bin/sh`, and the commands processing `"$file"` will be run by whatever `sh` that comes first in the PATH, which may behave differently than `/bin/sh`. This is a potential source of unexpected bugs. The `#!/usr/bin/env sh` shebang solves this problem, as all the commands will be run by the `sh` that is first in your PATH.

The only potential disadvantage of the `#!/usr/bin/env sh` shebang is the fact that `/usr` might not be mounted at the time of invoking the script. However, this shouldn't occur often in practice. External programs frequently used in portable scripts, such as `awk`, are also often found in `/usr/bin`, so it might be difficult to make sure the script runs correctly with `/usr` unmounted anyway.

If you really want to be portable and not depend on `/usr` being mounted, you can begin your script as follows, to make sure it is always executed by `sh` from the PATH, wherever it is:

```
#!/bin/sh
if test X"$SUBSHELL" != X"1"; then
  SUBSHELL=1
  export SUBSHELL
  exec sh "$0" "$@"
  exit 1
fi

# ... your actual script comes here ...
```

But it does seem to be a bit of an overkill, so I'd say the `#!/usr/bin/env sh` shebang is a reasonable compromise.