# avoid bashism in configure

Tags: r, bash, configure

I am creating a `configure` file for an R package. So far, the R/C++ parts of the code are ok, but when I run `devtools::check()` to check for my code integrity/quality, I get a note (i.e., a soft warning) about my `configure` file that says `possible bashism in configure line XX ('command' with option other than -p)`

This is the part of `configure` that R doesn't like:

```bash
# Extra checks on MacOS for SSL support in libpq
# command -v is probably fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/946850
if [ `uname` = "Darwin" ] && [ `command -v pkg-config` ]; then
  if pkg-config --atleast-version=12 libpq; then
    case "`pkg-config --libs --static libpq`" in
    *crypto*)
      echo "Local libpq has SSL support"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Local libpq does not have SSL support"
      FORCE_AUTOBREW=1
      ;;
    esac
  else
    FORCE_AUTOBREW=1
  fi
fi
```

Should I ignore that or should I write that part in a general way? If the right way is the 2nd way, which would be a good practice to write these kind of configurations?

Sorry if this is a noob question. I am a statistician trying to learn something that is not what I readily available in R/SPSS.

Comment: Add a POSIX shell shebang, then use shellcheck as your current script contains errors and deprecated syntax. ShellCheck will tell you exactly what and link you to relevant documentation to help you fix it.

Comment: I don't see what *I* think of as bashisms there, but good idea to let a machine debug it for you. Let us know what you find. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, at least now know what to find, here is one relevant answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53116875/3720258. Another relevant search shows that a POSIX compatible solution is -v, which I added but the check doesn't like it https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/3720258

Comment: `command -v` is not a bashism.

Comment: See the relevant POSIX spec at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html#tag_20_22

Comment: now, where there _is_ an obvious bug is ```[ `uname` = "Darwin" ]```; that should be ```[ "`uname`" = Darwin ]``` -- quotes are needed around the command substitution, they _aren't_ needed around the constant string that contains no potential syntax.

Comment: Thanks! Bash is zero obvious to me, I write some scripts and if those work, I consider those to be good, but I am not an artist of bash.

Comment: ...I wonder if the concern is compatibility with pre-POSIX shells. `command -v` is guaranteed in any POSIX-y shell (which is to say, any shell compliant with early-90s specifications), but configure scripts often try to be compatible with 1970s-era Bourne (aka "Heirloom sh").

Comment: ```if [ "`uname`" = Darwin ] && [ `command -v pkg-config` ]; then``` 
also says "possible bashism"

Comment: ...checking, `command -v` is definitely there in the 1994 issue of POSIX.2; I haven't found a copy of the earlier versions of the spec to see if it's there in the original 1992 release.

Comment: BTW, you should probably use quotes in ```[ "`command -v pkg-config`" ]``` for the same reason. It's _unlikely_ that the difference will matter, but if your PATH contains an entry with a directory with a space in it, or your IFS is set to `/`, bad things would happen without those quotes. Won't help with the warning, though -- afaik that's either a bug or excessive stringency (checking for compatibility with shells that were obsolete before a lot of folks here were born).

Comment: (BTW, using backticks for command substitution is _itself_ obsolete; `$(...)` is another feature that's been standardized since POSIX.2 was first published).

Comment: Or, just use `command -v pkg-config > /dev/null` instead of capture its output to test with `[`.

Answer (score 3):

The check is either wrong, or checking for compatibility with pre-POSIX Bourne shell; [the POSIX.2 standard requires `command -v` to work](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html#tag_20_22) and has since at least 1994 if not the initial publication in 1992; there's no genuine bashism here.

Answer (score 2):

what works with `devtools::check()` and returns 0 notes is

```bash
if [ "`uname`" = Darwin ] && [ "`command -v pkg-config`" ]; then
```

instead of

```bash
if [ `uname` = "Darwin" ] && [ `command -v pkg-config` ]; then
```

this solution is an "average" of all the comments in this thread

Comment: This is definitely more reliable code, but it's surprising that it suppresses a warning about bashisms; bash has the same bugs when executing the inadequately-quoted version as-currently-written. (It also has an _extended_ test operator, `[[`, which doesn't require the quotes for correct operation, but using that actually _would_ be a bashism; `[` is for this immediate purposes at feature parity either way)