moving launchpad.db with spaces
Consider the following script:
TODAY=$(date -j +"%j # %Y.%m.%d # %H.%M.%S")

LAUNCHPAD_LOCATION=$(getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR)com.apple.dock.launchpad
LAUNCHPAD_DESTINATION="/Users/tobias/[DEVELOPMENT # ROOT]/LOCAL/PROJECTS/sh # TK-Launchpad.DB/"$TODAY""

mkdir "$TODAY"
mkdir "$LAUNCHPAD_DESTINATION"

cp -Rv $LAUNCHPAD_LOCATION $LAUNCHPAD_DESTINATION


What's wrong with this script? It should copy the Launchpad.db folder to the recent date as formated in $TODAY but it doesn't. And yes, I need spaces for further file based processing and aesthetic purposes.
I tried copying the launchpad.db in a temporary folder without spaces and brackets and then moving the result in a new folder with spaces and brackets.
TODAY_1=$(date -j +"%j_#_%Y.%m.%d_#_%H.%M.%S")
TODAY_2=$(date -j +"%j # %Y.%m.%d # %H.%M.%S")

LAUNCHPAD_LOCATION=$(getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR)com.apple.dock.launchpad
LAUNCHPAD_DESTINATION_1="/Users/tobias/DEVELOPMENT_#_ROOT/LOCAL/PROJECTS/sh_#_TK-Launchpad.DB/"$TODAY_1""
LAUNCHPAD_DESTINATION_2="/Users/tobias/[DEVELOPMENT # ROOT]/LOCAL/PROJECTS/sh # TK-Launchpad.DB/"$TODAY_2""

cp -Rv $LAUNCHPAD_LOCATION $LAUNCHPAD_DESTINATION_1

mv -v "$LAUNCHPAD_DESTINATION_1" "$LAUNCHPAD_DESTINATION_2"


Now I'm getting nearly the result but now I have problem with this annoying subfolder and I don't getting this away.
By the way: Are there a simpler solution and maybe a working one?

[tag:sh] and [tag:zsh] are 2 very different shells, you can't be using both at the same time. Remove the tag for the one you are not using.

copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and read correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization.

It is very rare that a script is silently failing, without any error messages (and you didn't describe any message). Also, you didn't show the execution with tracing enabled (i.e. set -x), so we can't see the content of your variables either. Finally, as Ed Morton said, make up your mind what language the script is written in - sh or zsh.

@EdMorton: As far as I know sh is a shell which executes the systems standard shell. In my case it is zsh.

@ELSanchez no, sh is a shell, the Bourne Shell (different from Bash, the Bourne Again Shell, and different from zsh). It's possible on any system to alias sh to some other shell but don't count on it and doing so will often change the behavior of whatever shell it's aliased to so, for example, bash will behave differently if it's called as bash vs called as sh (i've no idea how zsh handles that, nor do I have any idea if sh on your system is aliased to bash or zsh or if it truly is just sh). Pick a shebang for whatever shell language your script is written in.

@user1934428: Sorry for the missing error statement or shell outputs. I only copy-pasted parts of my script and forgot this while trying to deal with quoting.

Complementing the answer by EdMorton: If you tag a question sh, you explicitly ask for bourne shell. If you tag a question shell (and no other shell tag), it means you are interested in POSIX shell behaviour. For other shells, at least tag the name of the shell you are going to use.  Hence, you can tag here just zsh or zsh and shell (to attract a wider audience), but the sh tag doesn't make sense and should be removed.

It's  OK that you forget things, but note that you can edit questions and add the missing details. If you don't, you risk that the question will be closed by the moderators.

The main reason behind this is that it does not handle spaces and special characters like brackets properly in the file path.
Remember whenever you are using variable or path that contain spaces, always try to wrap them in double quotes in order to ensure that the shell treats them as a single entity.
Try this one:
TODAY=$(date +"%j # %Y.%m.%d # %H.%M.%S")

LAUNCHPAD_LOCATION="$(getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR)/com.apple.dock.launchpad"
LAUNCHPAD_DESTINATION="/Users/tobias/[DEVELOPMENT # ROOT]/LOCAL/PROJECTS/sh # TK-Launchpad.DB/$TODAY"
mkdir -p "$LAUNCHPAD_DESTINATION"

cp -Rv "$LAUNCHPAD_LOCATION" "$LAUNCHPAD_DESTINATION"

I hope now it will resolve your query. In case if you find any doubt then ask again.

Correct quoting is the solution. I can understand why everybody is against using spaces in filenames but if I can handle quotation marks correctly which can get very complex then I think it is no problem and it looks pretty.

@ElSanchez : If you really would use zsh, as you claimed in your question, the quoting is redundant, because zsh does word splitting before parameter expansion. If quoting helped, I conclude that you are not running this script as zsh script.

@user1934428: My shebang line is: #!/bin/sh . I'm using macOS Monterey. The system shell is zsh and is linked to sh. Or in other words: sh is a link to zsh. I'm trying to be shell tolerant and therefore my brain says: #!/bin/env sh . But in an other article (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116226/what-is-the-recommended-posix-sh-shebang) says that would be not recommended.

@ElSanchez: But then, zsh does not behave like a usual zsh. Because it is called as sh, it runs in POSIX compatibility mode, which means it tries to act similar to POSIX. In this case, indeed the quotes are needed. I would  in this case tag the question just by shell; it does not hurt to mention in your text, that your POSIX shell is a zsh in POSIX mode. I personally don't favour this setup. What is the point in being "shell tolerant", and what exactly is it supposed to mean? I am using the zsh because I like its features, not to mimic the simpler POSIX shell.

@user1934428: I want to be as compatible for "every" shell, even if no zsh is installed. That is what I mean with shell tolerant. So I think with #!/bin/sh that goal would be achieved.

@ElSanchez: For "every shell" would be difficult. The best you can achieve is to run under any POSIX compatible shell (which means i.e. no arrays and other restrictions). This is just a different way of saying "I want to write a POSIX shell script". But you tagged your question as zsh. If you had removed the zsh tag, it would be more clear what you want to achieve, but tagging zsh means that you are looking for a zsh solution.
